# How to perform variable replacement within a stream when variables refer to objects within the stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm using Node and have a stream of objects. Each object contains strings that can refer to other objects; Essentially the objects are self-referencing within the stream. I want to replace those references with the values associated with the objects they refer to. However, this doesn't seem possible without first buffering the entire stream and then looping back over it to do the replacements.

Is there any technique that can do self-referencing variable replacement within a stream? I'm pondering the possibility of sidechain streams or buffers, but with no way to go back to older chunks, replacing them doesn't seem possible.

An example of the data looks like the following, however, instead of an array, each object is a chunk is an object.

```
translations = [
    key: 'client'
    parents: ['ui']
    values:
        en: 'THE COMPANY'
        fr: 'LE COMPANIE'
,
    key: 'title'
    parents: ['ui']
    values:
        en: 'hello ${ui.client} world2'
        fr: 'bonjour monde2'
]
```

References are done by parents + key, hence the `${ui.client}` reference. Every single object has a key while only some may have references.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of serializing references to other objects within a serialized stream is to create IDs for each object in the stream and replace the reference with an ID value and add the ID to each object in the stream.  Then, your code that interprets the serialized data must know which fields contain reference IDs and it can then replace those with references to the newly created objects.  Forward references in the stream are more work because you have to keep a list of pending reference IDs that you're waiting to find the host object that the reference refers to, but it can all be done.

Whenever I face a problem like this, I usually look for a simpler way to store the data that is not necessarily a direct representation of the live objects and then write some code the rebuilds the live objects from just the stored data, not a direct serialization, but sometimes much simpler to deal with.  Whether this works for you or not would totally depend upon your specific situation and data.

Comment: There's actually no serialization, just referencing by existing IDs/keys, but that doesn't matter. The problem is that the 2nd object may refer to the 1st object and the 1st object has already passed through the stream. There's no way for me to know which ones to keep for referencing and which to ignore without going through the entire stream at least once.

Comment: @Soviut - while streaming, you can keep track of all the objects with IDs in a lookup table so that future references to them can be filled in.  Or, depending upon your data structure, sometimes you can search for a given ID and find it to get the object reference.  If you want more specific help, you'll have to disclose the actual data that you're dealing with so we can get practical rather than just theoretical.